# How can i populate a sub Schema in different model in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I want to populate a model which has an ObjectId of a document which is present as sub schema on another model

Sub Schema

```
var addressSchema = new Schema({
    address: String,
    phoneNumber: Number,
    name: String,
    pincode: Number,
    augmontAddressId: String,
});
```

Main Schema - address is an array that can have multiples addresses and each object has its own objecId which i want to refer to

```
var userSchema = new Schema(
    {
      name: String,
        address: [addressSchema],
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
);
```

Ledger Schema referencing to Main Schema

```
var ledgerSchema = new Schema(
    {
        txnId: String,
        paymentId: String,
        addressId:{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User",
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
);
```

I tried

```
LedgerSchema.findById().populate("addressId").then(res=>{
    console.log(res);
})
```

But its not populating the addressId instead sending null value

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("650c49a20483f1ec8eb7aecd"),        
  addressId: null,
  createdAt: 2023-09-21T13:48:18.667Z,
  updatedAt: 2023-09-21T13:48:18.667Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

Also i tried setting ref in ledgerSchema as 'User.address'
But it gives an error

```
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "User.Address".
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh how nice it would be if you could just do `User.address` to reference things. Unfortunately, this can't be done with `populate` due to the way you have set up your subdocuments. In your `userSchema` each `address` is essentially a subdocument that is **embedded** in the top-level document. In contrast, within in your `ledgerSchema`, each `addressId` is a **referenced** document and are separate top-level documents.

My advice would be to change your `userSchema` so that each `address` is a **referenced** document but that will create another collection in your database (`addresses`). You need that to do references.

If for whatever reason you cant modify your schema and need to keep each `address` as an **embedded** subdocument then you can achieve the desired result with [aggregate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html). It is not a trivial task and it is not pretty but it does work:

```js
const ledger = await ledgerModel.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) } }, //< Your ledger _id
    {
        $lookup: //< Do a lookup to match addressId with userSchema.address._id
            {
                from: "users",
                localField: "addressId",
                foreignField: "address._id",
                as: "address_details" //< This creates a new array
            }
    },
    { $unwind: '$address_details'}, //< Now you need to unwind the new array
    { $unwind: '$address_details.address'}, //< And unwind each address
    {
        $project: //< This stage only outputs the original ledger properties
            {
                txnId: 1,
                paymentId: 1,
                address_details: 1,
                compare_address_ids: { $cmp: [ "$addressId", "$address_details.address._id" ] },
               //^ Compare addressId against ones done via lookup to find a match
            }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            compare_address_ids: 0 //< 0 means they matched
        }
    },
    {
        $project: //< Now get rid of these two made up properties from the output
            {
                compare_address_ids: 0,
                'address_details.name': 0,
            }
    }
]);
```